# ResponseMode="File" not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, custom-error-pages, http-error

I want to add simple html pages as custom errors for IIS.
So i add `404.html` and `500.html` pages to project and add next configuration :

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

Html pages are in `Views/Shared` folder.
But every time when i go to some unexisting path `/foo/bar` i just get error message `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` which is not mine.

For custom errors for ASP.Net i add next configuration :

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Home/404">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Home/500" />
</customErrors>
```

and remove `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` this line from FilterConfig file.

I found that possible problem in correct path to html pages or change `/` to `\` but noone solution that i found didn't help me.

---

I use IIS7+

Comment: Are your files 404.html & 500.html directly under the project main folder? If not, you have to specify the relative path from server. If they are in Views/Shared you have to mention path="Views\Shared\404.html" etc.

Answer (score 9):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpErrors/error) to this setting is clumsy.

---

If **responseMode** of **httpErrors** **error** element is set to **File**, **path** is considered as a file path (use \ to separate directories).

---

Path needs to be relative to the directory that contains web.config file with this setting.

If html file is in Home directory (site root \Home\404.html) and

- web.config is in site root, path will be **Home\404.html**
- web.config is in site root\Home, path will be **404.html**

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <remove statusCode="400" />
      <remove statusCode="401" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="Views\Erro\PaginaNaoEncontrada.html" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="400" path="Views\Erro\RequisicaoInvalida.html" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="401" path="Views\Erro\AcessoNegado.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: You should provide some more context as to what the code in your answer does and why :)